# Android Studio 0.8.6 multiple values folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using multiple values folders like values-hdpi ,values-xhdpi , values-xxhdpi folders to support multiple screen sizes. Lets say I have a dimension named "listitemheight" in all that values folders with different density pixel values.My question is, when I select between Nexus S(hdpi) and Nexus 5 (xxhdpi) Design rendering of Android Studio IDE does not pick specific dimension for the screen size .Is there any way to do that correctly ?

In values-hdpi

```
<dimen name="listitemheight">30dp</dimen>
```

In values-xxhdpi

```
<dimen name="listitemheight">70dp</dimen>
```

EDIT : It always chooses hdpi folder

[image: all files under res file]

Comment: the filenames of the dimens.xml are the same in all folders?

Comment: @SatelliteSD that's how it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Gumbo, yes correct, but if there was a difference, we may would have pinned down the problem.

Comment: When I was using Eclipse IDE, it was working like a charm. But in Android Studio I can not figure it out what is wrong with that.

Comment: check the build.gradle of the app-module for differences in the manifest.xml. Gradle overrides values in manifest.xml with values from build.gradle. I cant tell if it helps, but I would at least doublecheck it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using folders with names like "values-w600dp" . I had the same problem with you and this was the solution for me.

> Starting with API Level 13 (Android 3.2), the screen sizes are deprecated in favor of using the swdp qualifier. This new qualifier declares the amount of space a given layout needs. It is strongly recommended that applications that are meant to run on Android 3.2 or higher should be using these newer qualifiers.
>
> For example, if a layout required a minimum 700dp of screen width, the alternate layout would go in a folder layout-sw700dp

Source : http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/